# Writing to disk in units of a 'page'

Tags: database-design, file-io

Recently, I have been reading Database Management Systems (Raghu Ramakrishnan and Johannes Gehrke). It says, the disk space manager is responsible for allocation/deallocating/read/write operations in units of a page to ensure maximum amount of data manipulation in one head read/write to minimize time. Now to achieve, say a function, to write one page to disk can I do as follows:-

1-Write n bytes of data to a buffer in memory, where n is the page size

2-Write this buffer to a file using simple file I/O operations in C++ (ofstream).

My question is, will these n bytes be successfully written as one single page on disk, or will there be other distortions when using this process which prevents the buffer from being written to a disk as one single page of data despite its size being equal to the page size. In case, it won't be written as one page, what method do I have to adopt? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, database systems would use direct I/O to persist the page in memory to disk. Database systems could control, estimate, and optimized disk writing by direct I/O, which is not buffered by OS or buffered libraries.

You could reference OS's system call with following links:

1. [UNIX-Like: open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) : check out the **O_DIRECT** flag
2. [Windows: CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) : check out the **FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH**

Even if buffered I/O libraries have **flush()** method, OSs won't guarantee that data would persist to disk right way when flush() get called.